# what i can do for changing state without re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchMovies } from "../../feautures/movies/moviesSlice";

import { BiLeftArrow, BiRightArrow } from "react-icons/bi";

import Card from "../Card/Card";
import Slider from "../UI/Slider/Slider";
import Navigation from "../Navigations/Navigation";

import "./MoviesList.scss";
import request from "../../requests";

const MoviesList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Current Page

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  // Handle movies states
  const moviesStatus = useSelector((state) => state.movies.status);
  const moviesState = useSelector((state) => state.movies.movies);
  const moviesError = useSelector((state) => state.movies.error);
  const moviesHeading = useSelector((state) => state.movies.moviesHeading); // It's for pagination

  // Handle header input
  const inputValue = useSelector((state) => state.movies.inputValue);

  // Handle movies heading
  const moviesMoviesHeading = useSelector(
    (state) => state.movies.moviesHeading
  );

  // Movies according input values
  const filteredMovie = moviesState.filter((movie) =>
    movie.original_title.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue)
  );

  // Handle Page Number
  const handlePageNumber = (rotation) => {
    if (rotation === "goPrev" && currentPage >= 2) {
      setCurrentPage((prev) => prev - 1);
      console.log("current page: ", currentPage);
    } else if (rotation === "goNext" && currentPage < 10) {
      setCurrentPage((prev) => prev + 1);
      console.log("current page: ", currentPage);
    }
  };

  // Handle Pagination
  const prevNextPage = () => {
    if (moviesHeading === "POPULAR") {
      console.log("current page", currentPage)
      dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchPopular(currentPage)));
    } else if (moviesHeading === "NOW PLAYING") {
      console.log("current page", currentPage)
      dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchPopular(currentPage)));
    } else if (moviesHeading === "UP COMING") {
      console.log("current page", currentPage)
      dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchUpComing(currentPage)));
    } 
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (moviesStatus === "idle") {
      dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchPopular()));
    }
  }, [dispatch, moviesStatus]);

  let content;

  if (moviesStatus === "loading") {
    <div>selamlar</div>;
  } else if (moviesStatus === "succeeced") {
    content = (
      <div className="movies__container">
        <BiLeftArrow
          className="movies__arrow movies__arrow--left"
          onClick={() => {
            handlePageNumber("goPrev")
            prevNextPage()
          }}
        />
        {filteredMovie.map((movie) => {
          return <Card movie={movie} key={movie.id} />;
        })}
        <BiRightArrow
          className="movies__arrow movies__arrow--right"
          onClick={() => {
            handlePageNumber("goNext")
            prevNextPage()
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  } else if (moviesStatus === "failed") {
    content = <div>{moviesError}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="movies">
      <Slider />
      <div className="movies__heading">{moviesMoviesHeading}</div>
      <Navigation />
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MoviesList;
```

Hi guys have a good day.I try to make movie website with react-redux.But i stuck somewhere.When i click to right arrow button `handlePageNumber` function increase currentPage then i  pass this value to  `dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchPopular(currentPage)))` to go the next page.But when i click to right arrow button `currentPage` state still has 1 value.if click one more time `currentPage` has 2 value.Why doesn't it have a value of 2 when I first click it ? I guess value change after re-render if so what can i do ? Finally, if there is something bad in my code, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how i can code clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that React state updates are asynchronously processed, so the state update enqueued in `handlePageNumber("goPrev")` or `handlePageNumber("goNext")` hasn't processed yet when `prevNextPage()` is called on the next line, so `currentPage` is still the value from the current render cycle.

See this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) (*useState set method not reflecting change immediately*) for explanation.

## Solution

You can call the `prevNextPage()` function from a `useEffect` with a dependency on `currentPage`. Since `prevNextPage` isn't called elsewhere you can either define it ***within*** the `useEffect` callback and invoke it, or just move the old logic into the body of the `useEffect` callback. You'll need to include `moviesHeading` as a dependency as well.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (moviesHeading === "POPULAR") {
    console.log("current page", currentPage)
    dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchPopular(currentPage)));
  } else if (moviesHeading === "NOW PLAYING") {
    console.log("current page", currentPage)
    dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchPopular(currentPage)));
  } else if (moviesHeading === "UP COMING") {
    console.log("current page", currentPage)
    dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchUpComing(currentPage)));
  } 
}, [currentPage, dispatch, moviesHeading]);
```

And remove the call from the click handlers.

```
content = (
  <div className="movies__container">
    <BiLeftArrow
      className="movies__arrow movies__arrow--left"
      onClick={() => {
        handlePageNumber("goPrev");
      }}
    />
    {filteredMovie.map((movie) => {
      return <Card movie={movie} key={movie.id} />;
    })}
    <BiRightArrow
      className="movies__arrow movies__arrow--right"
      onClick={() => {
        handlePageNumber("goNext");
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

I might also suggest simplifying your `handlePageNumber` logic to consume a number value instead of a string, and clamp the value to your page range

```
// Handle Page Number
const handlePageNumber = (nextPage) => {
  setCurrentPage(page => Math.max(1, Math.min(page + nextPage, 10));
};
```

Add pass `1` or `-1` to the callback to go back a page, or forward to next page.

```
content = (
  <div className="movies__container">
    <BiLeftArrow
      className="movies__arrow movies__arrow--left"
      onClick={() => {
        handlePageNumber(-1);
      }}
    />
    {filteredMovie.map((movie) => {
      return <Card movie={movie} key={movie.id} />;
    })}
    <BiRightArrow
      className="movies__arrow movies__arrow--right"
      onClick={() => {
        handlePageNumber(1);
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.It was a very clear explanation :)

Comment: After i did what u suggest i get this error. `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'prevNextPage'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.I couldnt find any way to fix.

Comment: @UmutPalabiyik Sure, you could just move the entire `prevNextPage` function definition into the effect callback, but it's better to move the logic instead. I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: This time it thow this error `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`.Can u check my repo when u available.It works very well but i can figure out why this throw error :) https://github.com/UmutPalabiyik/hope-movie-app

Comment: @UmutPalabiyik According to the [react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) `dispatch` is a stable reference, but the react hook linting doesn't know this. It's completely safe and recommended to add it to the dependency array. In general you should add all dependencies that get flagged as missing unless you have good reason *not* to.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that react's setState method works async but you assumed it is sync method.
If I were you I store pagenumber in redux state. I write action to handle clicking prev/next buttons and send next page status (if currentPage = 8 then I send 9 for nextButton, and 7 for prevButton), after triggering this action, I handle the async operation with redux-thunk or redux-saga, and whenever I get the response from the middleware, I call success or fail action for this async operation which will handle next redux state